# Pass a compiler flag in Tensorflow android

Tags: android, cmake, tensorflow

I am using Android Java Inference Interface for TensorFlow (see [TensorFlow-Android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/f94e20f2c704f037a113d350fd7c431e3fd75df8/tensorflow/contrib/android) ).

I have two questions.

1. How can I pass compiler flag to build core tensorflow with selective registration? Should I put it into [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f94e20f2c704f037a113d350fd7c431e3fd75df8/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake/CMakeLists.txt) ?
2. How does `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable affect build? I mean initially, we build `libtensorflow-core.a` static lib (by uncommenting build_all_android.sh in gralde) then we build .so shared lib using `CMakeLists.txt`, and passing this flag to cmake seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `--copt` parameter to bazel ([basic docs](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/command-line-reference.html)):

```
--copt=<a string> multiple uses are accumulated
Additional options to pass to gcc.
```

The user manual has more extensive documentation on this option:
https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--copt